# Ansible, error when reading values from JSON response

Tags: json, ansible

In my Ansible-Code I have a task which makes some requests to check if a Cluster is created. Response of the Request is a JSON file which contains the values "healthy" and "status" and some more.

This is my Code:

```
 - name: Wait for Elastic Cluster to be ready
   uri:
     url: https://abcdefbla.{{ lookup('env','ENV') }}.some.url.com/api/v1/clusters/elasticsearch/{{elasticClusterDetails.elasticsearchId}}
     method: GET
     user: admin
     password: "{{rootpw.stdout}}"
     force_basic_auth: yes
     return_content: yes
     validate_certs: no
     register: result
     until: "{{ (result.stdout | from_json | first).healthy }}" == false and "{{ (result.stdout | from_json | first).status }}" == "started"
     retries: 60
     delay: 10
```

The from_json filter helps parsing the response, and the "first" tells that it should use the first key with that name. 
When I run it, I get the following error:

> ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
>     did not find expected key.
>   The error appears to have been in '/home/ubuntu/MLAAS-V2_USETHIS/mlaas-v2-aws/mls_ece_core/play.yml': line 295, column 65, but may
>   be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
>   The offending line appears to be:

```
 register: result
 until: "{{ (result.stdout | from_json | first).healthy }}" == false and "{{ (result.stdout | from_json | first).status }}" == "started"
                                                            ^ here
```

> We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
>   missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
>   start a value. For instance:

```
with_items:
  - {{ foo }}
```

Should be written as:

```
with_items:
  - "{{ foo }}"
```

As you see, I quoted the line as suggested. Any Ansible-Expert out there who can tell me what I am missing?!

Comment: Try  `(result.stdout | from_json | first).healthy }} == false` . Remove all mustaches, they aren't needed in conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. There was an error with spacing for the URL object. Later, an error with JSON parsing came up which I also fixed. The following code worked for me:

```
- name: Wait for Elastic Cluster to be ready
     uri:
       url: https://abcdefbla.{{ lookup('env','ENV') }}.some.url.com/api/v1/clusters/elasticsearch/{{elasticClusterDetails.elasticsearchId}}
       method: GET
       user: admin
       password: "{{rootpw.stdout}}"
       force_basic_auth: yes
       return_content: yes
       validate_certs: no
     register: result
     until: resultA.json.healthy == false and "started" == "{{ resultA.json.status|lower }}"
     retries: 60
     delay: 10
```